# Marshalling and Unmarshalling ResultSet: Dealing with empty strings

Tags: java, jdbc, marshalling, unmarshalling

When I'm creating instances of domain objects from a ResultSet, should I convert Strings which are null to an empty String. Conversely, when writing to the database should empty Strings be converted to null Strings?

What's best practise here? Or is it just dependent on the application?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty string, `""` is a string just as any other. To me it, storing `""` as `NULL` makes as much sense as storing `""` as `''` and storing `"abc"` as `NULL`.

**So, keep things simple:** Store `""` as `''`, and store a `null` reference as `NULL`.

---

To quote the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html):

> *The concept of the `NULL` value is a common source of confusion for newcomers to SQL, who often think that `NULL` is the same thing as an empty string `''`.*

Comment: Thanks @aioobe. Yes, that's my thinking too though though this will lead to lots of "if != null".

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you should keep nulls as nulls. Depending on your DB schema, empty string and null are two distinct values. If you conflate those values, your code may produce unexpected results -- especially if you have multiple developers working on the same code base. You may have to account for both cases in downstream code, but that will most likely be clearer and more maintainable/testable.